# When to set onClickListener with View and when with Button?

Tags: android, class, button, view

I have just started to learn Android Application Development from thenewboston.com  tutorials.

I had a confusion with setting the onClickListener event handler. When setting it for a button in the main activity, they used the Button class.

```
    redButton.setOnClickListener(
      new Button.onClickListener(){
              public void onClick(View v){
                 // Do Something 
             }
        }
    );
```

But when setting it for a fragment they used the view class.

```
    redButton.setOnClickListener(
          new View.onClickListener(){
                  public void onClick(View v){
                     // Do Something 
                 }
            }
        );
```

What is the difference between the two ? And when to use them ?
Please Help !!

Comment: activity also we can use View

Comment: Button class is derived from View class.So you can set click listener from either of the type and compiler won't complain you.Better to use the specific listener type always.In this case use "Button.onClickListener".

Comment: but when i used the Button class the app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

In Button also, you can use View also as you are using in fragment.
Actually both works identically.It is just the way you want to go for better solution than other.

For more details you could refer:

[setOnclickListener vs OnClickListener vs View.OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479647/setonclicklistener-vs-onclicklistener-vs-view-onclicklistener)

[Difference between specifying the view.onclicklistener and just having onclicklistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421330/difference-between-specifying-the-view-onclicklistener-and-just-having-onclickli)

Answer (score 0):

[Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) is derived class of [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.htm), so `onClickListener` of `Button` is overridden from `onClickListener` for `View`.

And **there is no difference between two implementations**.

In the [documentation for button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) example uses `view.onClickListener`

> ```
>  final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
>  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>      public void onClick(View v) {
>          // Perform action on click
>      }
>  });
> ```

so that seems the recomanded way.

Comment: Thanks!! It was a very simple explanation. I have read your answers on some other posts as well relating to android. As I am just starting to develop for android I had some questions. I wonder if you could just give me your email ID so I may contact you?

Comment: we can have chat on SO.

Comment: I don't know how it works. Would be glad if you would start. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

`Button.onClickListener()` could only be used for `Button`. But `View.onClickListener()` could be used for any view. So what is the right way of doing it?

Well, what you have currently done is called 'setting an anonymous listener`. That's bad. More info here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/110113

The best way to do is let your `Activity` or `Fragment` implement the `View.onClickListener()` and the override the `onClick()` method.